# Why don't I need to use bash indirection with string substitution?

Tags: indirection

One challenging thing I've encountered in bash scripting is using variable expansion in a recursive way.

However, I was able to figure out [through ChatGPT] that I could use indirect subsitution to reference positional parameter values:

```
linkerArgs+=("${!i}")
```

However, if I am using string substitution, it's fine for me to just use expansion in a recursive manner as you would figure logically:

```
"${x// /$newChar}"
```

Why does the bash interpreter consider the latter type of expansion (with just the dollar sign inside the brackets) as "bad substitution" when used in the context of assigning items to an array, but not with string substitution?

Comment: "Why" is a tricky question. The answer is often just ... because that's how the grammar is defined. Is that the answer you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

In substition, you are using the embedded variable in a different position of the syntax. It is not computing the name, but an argument.

This works in classic POSIX substitution like `${var#replacement}`. Inside `replacement`, we can have substitutions.

```
$ A=B
$ B=42
$ echo ${$A}
bash: ${$A}: bad substitution
$ echo ${!A}
42
```

but:

```
$ echo ${B}
42
$ echo ${B%2}
4
$ C=2
$ echo ${B%$C}
4
```

You can see that `$C` works as well as the literal `2` in the `${B%<tail-pattern-to-chop>}` syntax.

The `${!A}` syntax is a Bash extension. Why isn't it the obvious `${$A}`?

It is hard to speculate. This is a very old Bash feature; it is already present in the `bash-2.0` tarball from 1996 that was imported at the start of the current Bash git repository.

The Make language, by contrast, does the obvious thing for computed variables, exemplified by `$(OBJS_$(this_file))`.

This is pure speculation, but that may be the issue. If we look at computed variables in Make, they are not restricted to `$($(...`. The interior of the `$(...)` can contain variables anywhere.

If someone finds that `${$A}` works in the shell, where `A` gets replaced to `B`, the expectation is that something like `${abc_$A}` also works whereby the `abc_B` variable is computed and expanded.

And thus, possibly, the implementor/inventor of `${!A}` wasn't willing to take it that far.

Another possibility is that the other `${!` features like `${!name[@]}` already existed before that one; and so it was piggy-backed onto that syntax, giving a meaning to `${!word}` when `word` is not followed by `@`, `*`, `[*]` or `[@]`.
It's easy to fit a new extension into the syntax of an existing extension because it reduces the amount of reasoning about what could break; only programs which use the existing extension are affected.

Unfortunately, GNU's FTP repository provides only a `bash-1.14.7.tar.gz` tarball, and a `bash-2.0.tar.gz` tarball. Nothing in between. The 1.14.7 version has no expansions in the form `${!...}`. It doesn't yet implement arrays, for that matter.  The 2.0 version implements all the `${!...}` syntax: `${!word}` as well as `${name[@]}` and so forth.  We don't have the detailed history in between to be able to tell which came first.

As a last resort, we can interview Chet Ramey. I suspect the answer will be something like that multiple extensions were being added to variable expansion, and indirect references were just bolted into the same syntax rather than getting their own. I.e. when Bash sees `${!` means "process various Bash extensions after this point".

Comment: Fourth paragraph in [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion): "If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), and parameter is not a nameref, it introduces a level of indirection. Bash uses the value formed by expanding the rest of parameter as the new parameter; this is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the expansion, rather than the expansion of the original parameter. "

Comment: I think this is about as close to an answer as i may be able to expect, the $ works recursively when we use parameter expansion for string editing, but not directly for getting a variables value. That is when we use indirect expansion.

Comment: @muru Good catch, thanks. It's documented under `${param}` with verbiage rather than its own syntax heading. Yikes. Very bad for discoverability.  I would never have suspected that I have to search for nothing but `!`. :)